# Sqlite Foreign Keys

Tags: c, sqlite, haskell, hdbc

I try to enable foreign keys using HDBC-sqlite3 haskell library. This library uses a little helper c - function

```
int sqlite3_open2(const char *filename, finalizeonce **ppo)
```

which calls in turn `sqlite3_open` one.
In the [sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_db_config) I've found nice `sqlite3_db_config` function which is supposed to enable foreign keys. To test it I've added quickly 2 lines into `sqlite3_open2` (the two last ones of the listing):

```
int sqlite3_open2(const char *filename, finalizeonce **ppo) {
  sqlite3 *ppDb;
  finalizeonce *newobj;
  int res, *resFK, resFK1;

  fprintf(stderr, "DB pointer: %d\n", ppDb);

  res = sqlite3_open(filename, &ppDb);

  resFK1 = sqlite3_db_config(ppDb, 1002, 1, resFK);                    
  fprintf(stderr, "\nForeign Keys: ON/OFF:%d  ERR:%d\n", resFK, resFK1);  

  ...
```

My surprise was the result: `Foreign Keys: ON/OFF:0  ERR:1`.

Could somebody give me a hint what am I doing wrong or what would be the proper way of enabling foreign keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled,
>   it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the
>   PRAGMA foreign_keys command. For example:
>
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
>
> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
>   compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database
>   connection separately.

So, after your `sqlite3_open()`, you probably want to add the following:

```
sqlite3_exec(ppDb, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;", 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: your solution works. You've opened my eyes in respect how to solve my problem on Haskell level. Once I finish it I'll post it here.

Answer (score 3):

I had difficulties with enabling foreign keys using **HDBC-sqlite3** API because mentioned PRAGMA required to be invoked beyond transaction and the library opens in background a new transaction after connection gets established and after each commit. Still the workaround was easy:

```
main = do
   conn <- connectSqlite3 "test.db"
   runRaw conn "COMMIT; PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; BEGIN TRANSACTION"
```